# Libraries/suggestions for file-text searching/string split efficiency/how to make my code run faster

Tags: java, string, file, search

So,I've got like a text file that has 500.000 lines,and each of the lines has at most 100 words,separated by whitespace and numbers.I take each word from each line and search that respective string in several other files in my project(that are something like local dictionaries I made),that can either have or not have that word.Basically,at input I have the 500k file,and at output the same file,only with words in english(must be translated if they are found in another language).My question is,how can I optimize the code to run faster(right now,it takes ~1minute30seconds to processes around 10 lines,so in theory,it would take at least 5 freaking days to processes the whole file),and I've got to try and make it take at most 1 day.Now,here is how I do the search :

```
BufferedReader bufin = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("text_to_be_translated.txt"));
FileWriter fout = new FileWriter("Translated.txt", true);

            for (i =0; i < 500000; i++) {

                insertLine = new StringBuilder();
                Line = bufin.readLine();
                String[] array;
                array = Line.split(" ");
                for (String item : array) {
                    if (!isWord(item)) {
                        insertLine.append(item).append(" ");
                    } else {
                        if (isEnglish(item)) {
                            insertLine.append(item).append(" ");
                        } else {
                            check = getTranslate(item);
                            if (!check.equals(item)) {
                                insertLine.append(check).append(" ");
                            } else { insertLine.append(item).append(" ");
                                   }
                        }
                    }

                }

                fout.write(insertLine.toString() + lineSeparator);


            }
             fout.close();
            bufin.close();
```

The getTranslate method :

```
public static String getTranslate(String arg) {
        try {



            BufferedReader bread = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Dictionar.txt"));
            String Line;
            String[] array;


            while ((Line = bread.readLine()) != null) {
                array = Line.split(" ");

                if (array[0].equals(arg)) {
                    return array[1];
                }

            }

            bread.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return arg;
        }
        return arg;
    }
```

Comment: Your `getTranslate()` opens and reads the file every time you call it? I wonder why it's slow.

Answer (score 0):

First, as Kayaman said, you should open the dictionnary only once.

Then, you should put your input `text_to_be_translated.txt`in an array ordered (from A to Z).

After that, you should keep your progression in parsing the dictionnary so that you only move forward in it and you don't have to parse it from the beginning every time (since the input is ordered, and assuming the dictionnary is ordered)

Answer (score 0):

Can you put your whole "Dictionary" in a map? Or is it too big?
If it fits in a map, you could build a map before reading "text_to_translate". Then each access to the dictionnary would be of complexity O(1) (at best).

```
Map<String, String> dictionary = initializeDictionary()
...
...
```

And getTranslate :

```
public static String getTranslate(Map<String, String> dictionary, String wordToSearch) {
    String translation = dictionary.get(wordToSearch);
    if(translation == null){
      return wordToSearch;
    }
return translation;
```